# Probability of missing the next 2 shots

Tags: probability

> Kobe Bryant is a 90% free throw shooter. What is the probability that he will miss both his 2 next shots?

**Solution:**

$P(MISS) = P(M) = .10. P(M,M) = .1×.1 = .01= 1 \%$ of the time. He makes both $.9×.9=.81= 81 \%$ of the time. Miss,Make is $.1×.9 = .09 = 9 \%$ of the time. Make,miss is $.9×.1=.09=9 \%$ of the time.Note: $1 \% + 81 \% + 9 \% +9 \% = 100 \%$.

Is it correct that the answer is $9 \%$?

Answer (score 3):

No, the answer is $1 \%$. As you said, the probability that Kobe misses twice is $ .1×.1 = .01= 1 \%$.

You can confirm your answer by subtracting all the other outcomes from $1$. You have $1 - 0.81 - 0.09 - 0.09 = 0.01$, which is what we expect.